# Unexpected resolutions when aggregating rasters with raster package in R

Tags: raster, r, aggregation

I have a (near) global raster of elevation data in WGS84 with a resolution of 0.00893153 x 0.00893153. I am trying to aggregate it to a resolution of 0.166667 x 0.166667 with the following:

```
fact = 0.166667/res(elevation_raster)[1]
aggregated <- aggregate(elevation_raster,fact=fact)
```

However, when I do `res(aggregated)` I get `[1] 0.1706799 0.1706799` where I would expect `[1] 0.166667 0.166667`.

I'm confused as to why this is happening and can't find anything in the documentation which would suggest a reason for this discrepancy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` function decreases resolution *x* times according to `fact`. Since it's *x* times, `fact` is a positive integer. This is stated in description:

> **fact** postive integer. Aggregation factor expressed as number of cells
> in each direction (horizontally and vertically). Or two integers
> (horizontal and vertical aggregation factor) or three integers (when
> also aggregating over layers). See Details

If you need a specific resolution, use [projectRaster](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/projectRaster) function. You can specify the desired resolution with `res` and the method for computing the new values (nearest neighbor or bilinear). If you are modifying resolution to match with another raster, use that raster as template with this function.

Also, [resample](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/resample) function could be used if you have a raster layer as template.

Comment: The `projectRaster` function very quickly maxes out the RAM on my machine but I will try the `resample` method with a template to see how that goes

Comment: @A.Bollans I recommend you to move from `raster` to `terra` package. Most functions have the same syntaxis and it's faster than `raster`

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `projectRaster` in terra, or would i need to use `project` and then `resample`/`aggregate`?

Comment: @A.Bollans the equivalent is `project`. Use only one function: project or resample/aggregate. Check page 7 in library documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/terra.pdf